# Calculator disagrees with my summation calculation?

Tags: calculus, summation, summation-method

I’m given a very elementary problem. Solve the following summation for $n=100$:

$$\Sigma_{k=1}^n (5-4k)$$

Which I solve as follows:

$$\Sigma_{k=1}^n 5 - 4\Sigma_{k=1}^n k$$

Which simplifies to:

$$5n - 4 ( \frac{n(n+1)}{2})$$

Or:

$$6n - 2n^2$$

So, I get the answer $-19400$ using this formula. However, when I use WolframAlpha to solve the summation as given, I get $-19700$. What’s going on?

Comment: $5n - 4 ( \frac{n(n+1)}{2})$ is not equal to $6n - 2n^2$.

Comment: One of the convenient features of WA is you can feed it a formula like 5n - 4n(n+1)/2 and see how it simplifies the expression. In this case we get $3n - 2n^2$ among several other forms. In cases where the comparison is less obvious, a hack is to write out the two formulas you think are equal, tell WA to subtract one from the other, and see if it gives the answer 0.

Answer (score 2):

$$5n-4\left(\frac {n(n+1)}2\right) = 5n-2(n^2+n) = 3n-2n^2$$

Comment: Well I feel stupid. Thanks!